# "try!" macro stopped working after Rust upgrade

Tags: rust

Here is a simple testcase, which still works on the [playpen](http://is.gd/Cpn3Y8):

```
use std::num;
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::convert::From;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Error(String);

impl From<num::ParseFloatError> for Error {
    fn from(err: num::ParseFloatError) -> Error {
        Error(format!("{}", err))
    }
}

fn parse(s: &String) -> Result<f64, Error> {
    Ok(try!(<f64 as FromStr>::from_str(&s[..])))
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", parse(&"10.01".to_string()));
}
```

However, after I built the latest rustc from git (now it's `rustc 1.1.0-dev (1114fcd94 2015-04-23)`), it stopped compiling with following error:

```
<std macros>:6:1: 6:32 error: the trait `core::convert::From<core::num::ParseFloatError>` is not implemented for the type `Error` [E0277]
<std macros>:6 $ crate:: convert:: From:: from ( err ) ) } } )
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<std macros>:1:1: 6:48 note: in expansion of try!
exp.rs:15:8: 15:48 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I'm unable to find out what's wrong. Why is the compiler unable to find my trait implementation?

Comment: Could you try calling `std::convert::From::from` directly (i.e. effectively expanding the macro) to help diagnose? `match s.parse() { Ok(f) => Ok(f), Err(e) => return Err(From::from(e)) }`.

Comment: Yes — error message is the same, but red line pointer is now under `From::from`.

Comment: I've just tried the same code with `u64` type and `ParseIntError` error — it works! So it seems that my problem is related only to `ParseFloatError`.

Comment: I see the same error with `rustc 1.1.0-dev (69e47c77b 2015-04-23) (built 2015-04-23)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like it is a bug: `std::num::ParseFloatError` and `<f64 as FromStr>::Err` are different types:

- the `impl` of `FromStr` for `f64` is [in `core`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/24e4e60ae8579d674c1eebb0298ee61471ddb6e6/src/libcore/num/mod.rs#L1341-L1382), and hence uses [a `ParseFloatError` type defined in that crate](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/24e4e60ae8579d674c1eebb0298ee61471ddb6e6/src/libcore/num/mod.rs#L1512), so any uses of `FromStr`/`.parse()` will get this type.
- `std::num` defines a [new `ParseFloatError` type](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/24e4e60ae8579d674c1eebb0298ee61471ddb6e6/src/libstd/num/mod.rs#L49), so an import from `std::num` gets this one.

The `impl From<num::ParseFloatError> for Error` is using the latter, while `<f64 as FromStr>::from_str(...)` is returning the former.

I opened [#24748](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24748) about it. I also opened [#24747](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24747) about improving the diagnostics to make this easier to debug in future.

One can work around this by insteading implementing the trait for `core::num::ParseFloatError`. You'll need to load the `core` crate with `extern crate core;` and will need some feature gates.

Comment: Thanks for investigation! Maybe you could suggest some temporary workaround (except downgrading rust)? It seems that there are no ways to implement `From<core::num::ParseIntError>` for `Error`.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "no way"? (I've edited a paragraph with a work around into the end of my answer.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, that definitely works. I did not load `core` crate.